# font in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

is it possible to bring another language font in iphone sdk and  to insert that font value (for example,chinese) in UILabel value? any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the font as a resource in the project, then load the font using CoreText but it's not trivial.

The main step is to create a CTFontDescriptor that will load the font. There is sample code in the iPhone SDK documentation that I can't quote, the name of the section I found useful is...

CoreText Listing 2-9 "Creating a font from serialized data"